# next.js app with Google oAuth authentication to serve both development and production env

Tags: next.js, oauth, environment-variables, google-oauth, next-auth

I'm trying to develop my app, while it deployed to a production server.

Next app worked fine with Google OAuth as Provider of library "next-auth" when
*Authorised redirect URIs* defined in GCP is "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google".

When deploying to production, I've changed the *Authorised redirect URIs* defined in GCP to "https://myDomain.../callback/google".

My question is **how can I preserve both environments, without switching the value in GCP .**

I do see that Authorised redirect URIs can be multiple values, but when I tried to add both urls to list, google raised a red flag and blocked the auth to my app(both env).

I guess that I might need to handle different responses in my oAuth callback, but next-auth lib seems to be doing it in a black box using the NextAuthOptions. (In addition NEXTAUTH_URL env var can be a single value only - env/prod url ...)